# how can 3 dots at the End of the Excerpt in blog designer plugin WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, blogs

Hello Guys I used blog deisgner plugin. i just want to 3 dots after excerpt end means content words end in front. please tell me how to do that. Thanks

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @hassan will you please tell me how to do that ??

Answer (score 0):

By default, the excerpt “read more” string at the end is set to '...' . To change the excerpt “read more” string using the excerpt_more filter add the following code to the functions.php file in your theme:

```
/**
 * Filter the excerpt "read more" string.
 *
 * @param string $more "Read more" excerpt string.
 * @return string (Maybe) modified "read more" excerpt string.
 */
function wpdocs_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return '[.....]';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'wpdocs_excerpt_more');
```

Source: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_excerpt/

Comment: but how can  i used this in blog designer ??

Comment: Never used it. Maybe you should submit support ticket at their website.